# Do new integrated kitchen faucets come with threads for adapters?

Tags: faucet

I use a [Python No Spill Clean and Fill Aquarium Maintenance System](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000255NXC) with my current kitchen faucet to change out my fish tank water.

I'm thinking about getting a new faucet and kitchen sink, but the faucets I'm looking at doesn't look like there are any threads to attach the adapter to.

Here are a couple samples from amazon of the faucets that I'm looking at:

- [VCCUCINE  Single Lever Pull Out Sprayer](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00WU28AIK)
- [Delta 9178-AR-DST Leland Single Handle Pull-Down Kitchen Faucet with Magnetic Docking](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00A39FSAK)

I've tried looking at the delta site and various terms such as garden hose adapter, but nothing useful came up.

Answer (score 1):

The second Delta faucet that you linked is not going to be at all compatible with your fish tank cleaning system. The first VCCUCINE unit may be usable if the aerator on the non-spray spout is removable. It looks like from the view below that it may be removable as per the small flats on two sides:

[image]

...but it would not be fun to have to remove that part every time you wanted to use the fish tank cleaning adapter.

**Also be aware that there a plethora of sizes of threads** used for faucet aerators. Some are internal (F type) threads and others are external (M type) threads. Then throw in inch and metric sizes and realize that there will be a good chance that your existing faucet adapter may not work with a new faucet even if it does have a conveniently removable aerator.

Comment: Thanks Michael. So would it be right to assume that the only faucets I should look for are 1, those with removable aerators that have threads and 2. threads that I can buy an adapter for to fit my cleaner. Assuming the two points above are true, is there a way to check the faucet for these two conditions other than to stop by the local hardware store? For example would it be listed in the specifications under some term I'm not familiar with?